# How to add a Path to update-alternatives --config php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plesk, php-7.2

I'm working on a Ubuntu 16 machine:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

My experience with Ubuntu is "medium".

I needed to change the path the `php` command refers to in alternatives.
I did the following:

```
cd /etc/alternatives
ls -ls | grep php
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Mar  7 06:31 php -> /usr/bin/php7.0
```

I want to change the path `/usr/bin/php7.0` to `/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php`.

The first thing I tried is `update-alternatives --config php`.
This gave me this:

There is 1 choice for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

```
  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Sadly, I can't add another path by using this command.

The second thing I tried to do is this: `update-alternatives --set php /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php`. The result of that:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php for php not registered; not setting
```

The third attempt, I went to `/etc/alternatives` and used `unlink php`. Then I created a new symlink like this: `ln -s /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php php`.
This changed the path in alternatives indead. See for yourself:

```
root@xxtweb03:/etc/alternatives# ls -ls | grep php
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26 Apr  4 12:18 php -> /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php
```

It has only one disadvantage. 
When I run this command: `update-alternatives --config php` then the `/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php` is not among the selection.

This is what I get:

```
root@xxtweb03:/# update-alternatives --config php
There is 1 choice for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode
```

Question: how can I add `/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php` to the Path list that is displayed when running `update-alternatives --config php`?

Answer (score 8):

you have to install alternative path first to display it in alternatives list,
see [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives)
by using this command,

`update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php 71`

it will install your `/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php` into alternatives list

Answer (score 6):

I had to append an additional and mandatory option `priority`. The value has to be an integer.

This worked for me:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php 100
```

Maybe you also want to add alternatives of these commands:

- phar
- phar.phar
- php-cgi
- php-cgi-bin

These commands will add alternatives for all five commands (also called link groups):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/phar phar /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/phar 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/phar.phar phar.phar /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/phar.phar 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php-cgi php-cgi /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php-cgi 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php php-cgi-bin /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php-cgi 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to adjust [Torsten Homberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61973353/1469223) for LSPHP 8.2 in Cyberpanel, Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/local/lsws/lsphp82/bin/php 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/phar phar /usr/local/lsws/lsphp82/bin/phar 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/phar.phar phar.phar /usr/local/lsws/lsphp82/bin/phar.phar 100
```

Then run

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

And selected

```
`* 4            /usr/local/lsws/lsphp82/bin/php     100       manual mode`
```

Hope this will help someone in the future, or myself, since I keep forgetting these settings.