# How to enable php-zip in laravel nativephp application

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive, native-php

I am using Laravel nativePHP package to generate desktop application

It's running fine but when I try to generate zip file with ZipArchive class, getting this error : `Class "ZipArchive" not found`

This is my controller code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use ZipArchive;

class Home extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show form
     *
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('generate-zip');
    }

    public function generateZip(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $file = $request->file('fileInput');
            $fileContents = file($file->getPathname());
            $folderPath = $request->textInput;

            $destination = public_path($folderPath.'/selected-images.zip');
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $zip->open($destination, ZipArchive::CREATE);

            foreach ($fileContents as $line) {
                $data = str_getcsv($line);
                $imgName = $data[0];
                if ($imgName) {
                    $localFilePath = $folderPath.'/'.$imgName;
                    $file = public_path($localFilePath);

                    if (File::exists($file)) {
                        $zip->addFile($file, $imgName);
                    }
                }

            }
            $zip->close();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->withError([$e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Actully, This code working fine on web browser but in nativePHP application showing error. When I have checked Zip extension is enabled or not by echo phpinfo();

In nativePHP application is not showing but on web browser showing enabled.

and also showing different php version for both nativePHP(8.2.8) or web browser(8.2.14)

So how to enable php-zip extation for laravel nativePHP aplication ?

phpinfo output On web browser :

[image]

phpinfo output On nativePHP Application :

[image]

How to fix this error(Class "ZipArchive" not found) and enable php-zip for nativePHP application ?

Thank you!

Comment: you have multiple php in your system?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple php in my system 8.1, 8.2 or 8.3. But when I have enabled php8.1 still nativePHP application shown 8.2.8 version and on web browser showing php8.1 ?

Comment: that means you will have to select same php 8.1 for terminal also.

Comment: Working fine when I switch php version for web browser or terminal both, I have run these command for switching php version 1) `sudo a2enmod php8.2` 2) `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2` 3) `sudo service apache2 restart`

Actually, **NativePHP** install own separate PHP which will use for desktop App, I am stacking in this PHP to enable PHP library ?

Comment: you should find any library that will work on both. otherwise you will all have to do it manually every time

Answer (score 0):

You can update the php version to the one with php-zip enabled by changing the php version used by the cli with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

[More information about updating the php cli version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513672/how-to-add-a-path-to-update-alternatives-config-php)